# Change status php ajax and script and value input

Tags: php, ajax, input

i am new in this domain , not even a junior , i am learning from home and i work on a message system...its almost done , my last thing to do its when someone click on new messages to change status from 1[new] to 0[old] these are my scripts... this work but this query change all my messages with status 1 to 0 and i need to change just by name of the sender.

These are my files : Here its the input with id of the script

```
echo " 
        
    <img style='display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;' src='images/newmessage.png'> 
   <a href='conversatie.php?catre=" . $row['nume'] . "'>
<input style='display:inline-block;font-size:15px;height:40px;  ' class='button' id='messagechangestatus' onclick='messagechangestatus()'  type='submit' value='".$row['nume']."'></a> ;
```

this its the script in the same page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("messagechangestatus").value;
    function messagechangestatus () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"includes/changestatus.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: x,
        success:function(result){
         alert(result);
       }
     });
 }
</script>
```

And here its my changestatus.php page :

```
<?php 

session_start();
require "conectare.php";


$author = $_SESSION['prenume'];

   


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE catre='$author' AND status='1'" ;


        $result = mysqli_query($conectare, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1){

        
            $author = $_SESSION['prenume'];   
            $sql2 = "UPDATE messages
                     SET status='0'  WHERE catre='$author'";


                     mysqli_query($conectare, $sql2);


            header("Location: mesaje.php");
            exit();

}

echo "Nu functioneaza";

?>
```

i want to make my sql query something like :

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE messages
                     SET status='0'  WHERE catre='$author' AND name =' ****And here to be the value of my input****   '";
```

What i can do next to get this value of input in my sql?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need to fix your ajax code
because you're sending nothing i think

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = ("#messagechangestatus").val();
          $.ajax({
            url:"includes/changestatus.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: { x : x },
            success:function(result){
             alert(result);
           }
         });
});
    </script>
```

Then in the changestatus.php you need to take the value of that var x which you sent through ajax in  data: { x : x }, by adding an if statement to look like this :

```
if(!isset($_POST['x'])){
echo "your error here which shows that you're not getting the value of that x variable";}
```

then here you can do your update to seems like this :

```
$messagechangestatus = $_POST['x'];

$sql2 = "UPDATE messages SET status='0'  WHERE catre='$author' AND name='".$messagechangestatus."' ";
```

Comment: I changed how you told me and i put $ after  var x =  and  i moved my changestatus.php from includes folder to principal because it gives me something like "404 not found in includes/mesaje.php" and mesaje.php was in my principal folder... so now it shows me all my html page.... i cant copy all error here... its too long

Comment: Make sure you're not including the database twice 
because when you're making an ajax call it means you're loading content of another page without refresh the whole page so try to comment the include of you're database there and see what's happening then

and for var x = ("#messagechangestatus").val(); and
var x = document.getElementById("messagechangestatus").value;
it's almost the same just the first one is a jquery syntext and the second is a java script one.
Let me know if your error is fixed.

Comment: I edited it and i used :  var x = document.getElementById("messagechangestatus").value;     instead of the old var x and it gives me the same result (in specified alert without even click the input alert on the page all my html code from !DOC to body ... i have one time db here in mesaje.php(where its the ajax but not in ajax) ; $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","db"); and in messagechangestatus.php ( i edited it from changestatus.php because i have 2 now) i have this : require "includes/conectare.php";  . Sorry for my english and for being that stupid but i know just a little php.

Answer (score 0):

Thx testovic , here its the answer :

in mesaje.php :

```
   <a href='conversatie.php?catre=" . $row['nume'] . "'>
<input style='display:inline-block;font-size:15px;height:40px;  ' class='button' id='messagechangestatus' name='messagechangestatus'  type='submit' value='".$row['nume']."'></a>
```

this is the script in mesaje.php  :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#messagechangestatus').on('click',function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("messagechangestatus").value;
          $.ajax({
            url:"messagechangestatus.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: { x : x },
            success:function(result){
           }
         });
});
    </script>
```

And this is in messagechangestatus.php :

```
<?php 


session_start();
require "includes/conectare.php";


$author = $_SESSION['prenume'];
$nume = $_POST['x'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE catre='$author' AND status='1'";


        $result = mysqli_query($conectare, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1){


if(!isset($_POST['x'])){
echo "Nici o valoare nu a fost trecuta in input";} 

        else {



        
            $author = $_SESSION['prenume']; 
            $nume = $_POST['x'];

            $sql2 = "UPDATE messages SET status='0'  WHERE catre='$author' AND nume='".$nume."' ";

                     mysqli_query($conectare, $sql2);

                 }

            exit();

}

echo "Nu functioneaza";

?>
```

Thank you very much again !